# Torrent Parser in java

Tags: java, bittorrent

Is there is any torrent parser available in java to extract the meta data from the .torrent files ...

Comment: I have written one, too. According to people who use it, it's complete and correct: https://github.com/m1dnight/a-torrent-file-parser-in-java

Answer (score 5):

An article on [wiki.theory covering the bitorrent spec](http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification) led to [BDecoder](http://www.koders.com/java/fid913FCFF784A3A1BEDE9E4D7BF38FAA7D21C61C1A.aspx), a decoder for the fileformat used by torrent to encode metadata. Have fun! (The page contains a link to a corresponding encoder too)

The easiest approach should be using the [Bittorrent API](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitext/). The provided lib contains a client, which should be capable of decoding metadata and include the java classes for that purpose.

---

Related questions:

- [Extracting metadata from torrents with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437420/extracting-metadata-from-torrents-with-java)
- [How can I generate a .torrent in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032876/how-can-i-generate-a-torrent-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [spec](http://fileformats.wikia.com/wiki/Torrent_file) to write up a parser yourself.  It shouldn't be too difficult.

Otherwise you could check out the source for any Java-based client.  [Azureus/Vuze](http://azureus.sourceforge.net/download.php) has their source available (don't see any information regarding license at first look).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [jtorrentparser](https://code.google.com/p/jtorrentparser/)

It parses an Array of shorts with the static parse() method:

```
TorrentParser.parse(short[]);
```